# script to convert date (month_name DD, YYYY) to (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: regex, scripting, date, html-parsing, text-parsing

I have a text file with dates in the form: "date=month_name DD, YYYY" and "date=(month_name DD, YYYY)"

How can I convert these dates so they are in the form: "date=YYYY-MM-DD"?

I also have some dates preceded by the field name "accessdate=" or no field name, that I would like to convert.

Thanks.

ADDENDUM:

- The month names are are the full English month names e.g. January, February, etc.
- I would only like to convert the dates inside ref tags i.e. they would be surrounded by other text inside `<ref></ref>'`
- I'm open to any language for the scripting. I've done a little bash, javascript & python. But I think awk, sed, perl, etc. would be also fine. Explanations of the code would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have any preference for the lanugage you use? Is this going to be PHP, shell script, Python, or something else?

Comment: also, are the month names long or short? (or a mixture of the two?) and are they in English?

Comment: See the addendum for the answers to your questions. As to to which language, you may choose the one you think is most efficient/easiest for a newbie to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with

```
echo 'date=April 13, 1985' | sed -e 's/January/01/' ... \
        -e 's/April/04/' ... -e 's/December/12/' | \
    sed 's/\([0-9]*\)[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)[^0-9] \([0-9]*\)$/\1-\2-\3/'
```

To handle "date=(month_name DD, YYYY)" you can also add `sed 's/date=(\([^(]*\))/date=\1/'` to the pipe and so on.

Concerning your addendum. sed would not be enough to work with `<ref></ref>` tag if it spans more then one line. So you have to use something more powerful. E.g. Python.

`re.search()` can be used to find `<ref>` and the matching `</ref>`. Then `re.match()` can be used to transform what's inside using the regexps similar to those used in sed. This algorithm have to be enclosed in a `while` loop to traverse all the document.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'll try out the method you suggested with re.search then re.match.

Comment: Note that in the above code, I needed to put  "| sed" before each -e in the parsing of the month name and it should be \3-\1-\2/ at the end to get it in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Actually I did't need to put "| sed", I had an error due to having a space after the '\' to break up the code into another line.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the tool you use.

E.g. with awk & sed you can do something like this:

```
 awk '{
        /date=(?Jan/ {print "s/\\(.\\+\\)date=(\\?month_name \\(\\d\\d\\), \\(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\))\\?\\(\.\\+\\)$/\\1date=\\3-01-\\2\\4"}
        /date=(?Feb/ {print "s/\\(.\\+\\)date=(\\?month_name \\(\\d\\d\\), \\(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\))\\?\\(\.\\+\\)$/\\1date=\\3-02-\\2\\4"}
        /date=(?Mar/ {print "s/\\(.\\+\\)date=(\\?month_name \\(\\d\\d\\), \\(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\))\\?\\(\.\\+\\)$/\\1date=\\3-03-\\2\\4"}
        # ...
}' INPUT_FILE > tmp.sed
```

Then you can do an

```
sed -i.ORIG -f tmp.sed INPUT_FILE
```

Or you can write it in pure awk, by parsing $0.